# Can we always multiply two matrices if the multiplication between them is permissible?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can we always multiply two matrices if the multiplication between them is permissible?

This question immediately comes to my mind when I studied the change of basis matrix from Artin’s book. It says that if $P= \left ( P_{ij} \right)$ be a change of basis matrix from $\mathbb B$ to $\mathbb B’$ then $\mathbb B’=\mathbb B P$. Though the matrix multiplication is permissible if we multiply $\mathbb B$ and $P$ we will get a $1 \times n$ matrix whose $j$-th column is given by $\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i} P_{ij}$ (here $\mathbb{B}=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$). Now my question is: “Is the product $v_{i} P_{ij}$ permissible for any $i,j$?” Because we know that multiplication of a vector in a vector space $V$ with an element of the field $\mathbb F$ (generally known as scalar) from the left is only permissible due to the fact that the external composition is a mapping from $\mathbb F \times V$ into $V$. But how can I determine whether $vc \in V$ or not for some vector $v \in V$ and for some $c \in \mathbb F$?

I am in a fix.I don’t know how can I write the transformed basis in the above fashion i.e. $\mathbb B’ = \mathbb B P$. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't told us what you mean by the notation $v_i$.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually here $\mathbb B = \{v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_n \}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: I would rather say that it's $P_{ij}v_i$ instead of $v_iP_{ij}$.

Comment: How does $v_i \in \mathbb F$? It's a basis vector of $V$.

Comment: But Artin referred it as $v_i P_{ij}$. How can it be possible?

Comment: Which book is this by Artin?

Comment: Second edition of the book "Algebra" written by Michael Artin.

Comment: @B.Pasternak look at the equation (3.5.7) in the page 93 of the said edition

Comment: Who downvoted me? Would you please tell me the reason for such downvote?

Comment: I am also curious as to who downvoted and why. I think that this is a fair question which shows thought and effort. I will therefore upvote it.

Comment: I have found the first edition, and there he introduces what I have introduced in my answer. He also says at some point: "The only new feature is that the definition of matrix multiplication has caused the scalar coefficients to migrate to the right side, which doesn't matter". This is precisely what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book at hand, but here is what I think. Strictly speaking you are correct, and it should be $P_{ij}v_i$, since we have defined multiplication by scalars from the left. However, $V$ with multiplication with elements of $\mathbb{F}$ from the right is isomorphic to $V$ with multiplication from the left, and we just don't distinguish between these two, and write $v_iP_{ij}$ or $P_{ij}v_i$, whatever suits us. The reason to write it like this is because in this way the basis transformation $\mathbb{B}^\prime=\mathbb{B}P$ can be understood as a multiplication of a row vector with a matrix, i.e. we write $\mathbb{B}^\prime=(v^\prime_1\ldots v^\prime_n)$ and $\mathbb{B}=(v_1\ldots v_n)$, and then
\begin{align}
(v^\prime_1\ldots v^\prime_n)&=(v_1\ldots v_n)
\begin{pmatrix}
P_{11}&\cdots &P_{1n} \\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
P_{n1}&\cdots& P_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\left(\sum^n_{i=1}v_iP_{i1}\cdots\sum^n_{i=1}v_iP_{in}\right).
\end{align}
Of course, this is really just a nice way to write $n$ equations, i.e. the equations $v^\prime_j=\sum^n_{i=1}P_{ij}v_i$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so that $\{v^\prime_1,\ldots,v^\prime\}=\mathbb{B}^\prime$. What we have done now is define an action of $GL(n,k)$ (invertible $n\times n$-matrices over $k$) on the set $\mathcal{B}$ of bases of $V$, which is actually a useful thing. For one, you know that any two bases are related by an invertible matrix, i.e. an element of $GL(n,k)$, and now you can define an orientation on your vector space: first, define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{B}$ by declaring $\mathbb{B}_1$ and $\mathbb{B}_2$ to be equivalent if and only there exists $A\in GL(n,k)$ with $\det(A)>0$ such that $\mathbb{B}_1=\mathbb{B}_2A$. It is easy to see that this is indeed an equivalence relation, and now we define an orientation of $V$ to be an element of $\mathcal{B}/\sim$ (note that there are precisely two orientations). There are more instances where this action is useful, but I think those are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @B.Pasternok why do yo take $A \in GL(n,k)$ to be such that $\det A > 0$? Where are there problems if we don't consider $A$ has positive determinant? I also don't understand the lines 
"...now
we define an orientation of $V$ to be an element of $\mathcal B/~$." Would you please tell me what is $\mathcal B/~$?

Comment: This is a choice you have, there are no problems if you don't. You can choose either $\det(A)>0$ or $\det(A)<0$, but it is customary to choose $\det(A)>0$, since the transformations with positive determinant are the ones we would like to call "orientation-preserving" (e.g. the identity!). I write $\mathcal{B}/\sim$ not $\mathcal{B}/$, and this is the set of equivalence classes with respect to the action of $GL(n,k)$ on $\mathcal{B}$ that I defined.